# javascript regex extracting match from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract, meaning find and completely remove match from a string.

```
let str = 'PROGRESS, 5 YEAR AVG, MEASURED IN PCT PLANTED';
let reg = /MEASURED IN\s{1}(\w+)+s{1}/u;
str.split(reg);
```

---

```
result: [ 'PROGRESS, 5 YEAR AVG, ', 'PCT', 'PLANTED' ]

desired result: [ 'PROGRESS, 5 YEAR AVG, ', 'PLANTED']
```

Comment: Just `const reg = /\bMEASURED IN\s+\w+/;`?

Comment: `str.split(/MEASURED IN\s+\w+\s+/)` should get you desired output

Comment: `s{1}` is equal to `s` and just matches an `s` letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to match `MEASURED IN PCT` with regex, replace, that value with an empty string, then do a split by comma and trim the values. The snippet below does the job:

```js
const str = 'PROGRESS, 5 YEAR AVG, MEASURED IN PCT PLANTED';
const re = /MEASURED IN \w+\s/;
const result = str
  .replace(re, '')
  .split(',')
  .map(value => value.trim());

console.log(result);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
str.split(/MEASURED\sIN\s\w+\s/);
```

If I have got it correctly